# How to access an event handler from one class to another class (Part 2) as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two classes called Guest and Guest2. I wanted to know is it possible to remove an eventlistener in the Guest class from Guest2 class. Below is the full code. Note: Both class have exactly the same code

```
package 
        {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.filters.*;

        public class Guest extends MovieClip
        {
            var walkSpeed:Number = 5;
            var oldPosX;
            var oldPosY;

            var myGlow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();

            public function Guest()
            {   
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addGlow);
            }

            function addGlow(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                filters = [myGlow];
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removeGlow);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);

            }

            function removeGlow(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                filters = [];
            }

            function ready(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                filters = [myGlow];
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, walk);
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, removeGlow);
                **MovieClip(root).Guest02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, walkTo);**
            }

            function walk(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                oldPosX = parent.mouseX;
                oldPosY = parent.mouseY;
                rotation = Math.atan2(oldPosY - y,oldPosX - x) / Math.PI * 180;
                filters = [];
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, walk);
                stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            }

            function loop(event:Event):void
            {
                var dx:Number = oldPosX - x;
                var dy:Number = oldPosY - y;
                var distance:Number = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
                if (distance<walkSpeed)
                {
                    // if you are near the target, snap to it
                    x = oldPosX;
                    y = oldPosY;
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

                }
                else
                {
                    x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                    y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                }

            }

            **function walkTo(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                _Guest02.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ready);
            }**

        }
    }
```

Comment: "Both classes have exactly the same code." Judging from your last two questions and that statement, I'm beginning to feel that you're a little unclear about the roles of classes and instances. Why do you have two separate classes with exactly the same code?

Comment: @Jake King: The reason I have 2 classes with the same code is because I have 8 guests all which functions the same way but used two for prototype reasons and instead of doing it in arrays or creating a separate class in which all will have access to I done it the long way so i myself have a full understanding as to what i'm coding. Both guests will be able to talk to each other so i understand i need a boolean but for now i want to know is it possible to remove event listeners for now from other classes, then i will work on arrays and for loops to make it efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As Jake King pointed out already, you might want to revisit your code in terms of object-oriented programming. If you say that both classes share the exact same functionality, why don’t you set up a class Guest and create two instances, e.g. guest1 and guest2.

As for your question regarding the event handlers, you need to store your listener in an instance variable that is either public and can then be accessed from another instance (bad style), or write a dedicated public function that allows for the removal of a listener, while the listener variable is kept private:

```
public class Guest extends MovieClip
{
    private var overListener;

    public function Guest()
    {   
        overListener = addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, addGlow);
    }

    public function removeOverListener() 
    {
        if (overListener) {
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overListener);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

If guest1 and guest2 were both instances of Guest and guest1 had a reference to guest2 stored, you could then remove a listener in guest2 from guest1 like so:

```
guest2.removeOverListener();
```

Comment: I understand what you saying. Another reason why I kept it a different class because each will have a different characteristics, hobbies, interests and different data storage's. I have 8 guests. What is the best way to tackle this. Should I create a separate class on which all 8 guests/class can have access to it and to each other.

Comment: Please do have a look into the fundamentals of object-oriented development, for instance [here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix/). It will very likely solve the problems you're facing in your concrete project.

Comment: @Saf What you're trying to do (having each instance of guest being able to access each other) is considered a bad pattern as it will couple your classes together making them impossible to recycle as individuals. What you want to do is have some higher tier manager type class that deals with the relationships between each guest. As for your classes themselves, you're on the right track but you should read about class inheritance in ActionScript 3 before continuing your project.

Comment: Ok so for the movement side of the code i should do it on a different class in which all 8 guest/class can have access to. Should i use arrays too for like selecting and talking.